# jmeter execute complex shell command

Tags: linux, shell, process, command, jmeter

Im using the OS Process Sampler to execute the following shell command

```
cat ${myDataFile} | myProcessor.sh --param1 valueParam1 --param2 valueParam2

command: cat 
Standard Input(stdin): ${myDataFile}
working directory: ${myHome}
command Parameters: | myProcessor.sh --param1 valueParam1 --param2 valueParam2
```

Response

```
cat: | myProcessor.sh --param1 valueParam1 --param2 valueParam2: No such file or directory
```

Clearly "cat" is tying to ca the command parameter as a file.

How to overcome this issue.  This is running on a AWS EC2 environment

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a pipe `|`, you need to start the command in a shell:

```
bash -c "cat ${myDataFile} | myProcessor.sh --param1 valueParam1 --param2 valueParam2"
```

Your question leaves it open when `${myDataFile}` will get expanded. I assumed it will get expanded by jmeter. If it should get expanded at runtime, you need to use single quotes:

```
bash -c 'cat ${myDataFile} | myProcessor.sh --param1 valueParam1 --param2 valueParam2'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to pass your `${myDataFile}` as a command **Parameter**, it shouldn't be simulating STDIN. See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation.
2. If you want to use pipe you need to call your command via shell interpreter (sh, bash, zsh, whatever). Invoke `echo $SHELL` command and read `man` entries on your shell to learn how to do it.